# How to set result value from geocode call?

Tags: javascript, geolocation

Hi I was trying to implement store the user current position into `MONGODB`, But I am not able to set  result value to **global_variable**?

Trying below code

Var global_variable;

```
getCurrentAddress(location) {
    this.currgeocoder.geocode({
      'location': location
    }, function (results, status) {

      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        console.log("Results:::" + JSON.stringify(results[0]));
        **global_variable = results;**

      } else {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
      }
    });
  }
```

But **global_variable** is **`undefined`**

Could you please some one help me. Thanks in advance !!

Comment: I think we need some more code here. Where is `global_variable` undefined? Where are you accessing the variable and for what purpose? Understanding your end goal may help us provide you or at least walk you through a solution.

Comment: Also, what is `this` referring to inside of your `getCurrentAddress` function? Is it properly scoped?

Comment: @wlh, I am just trying to console the global variable out side function, if i can get the global variable, i will store the MOngodb

Comment: See my second question about scope of `this`, which will play into the solution, but if you want to get the value out of the function, and the `getCurrentAddress` function is itself asynchronous, why not use a `Promise` or `async/await`, or even a `callback` to pass the value of `results` to the global?

Comment: can you give me the any example if possible @wlh, Please..

Comment: See my answer below. Of course, there are other and perhaps better answers, but for your usage of `this` in your question, give this e-book a good read: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes

Comment: @wlh, still i am not able to set the global value

Comment: I need to see more of the code going into this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one example for making your address call promise-based so you can get the data from your API call out to be able to pass to MongoDB. Of course the other option is the make your MongoDB call in the callback to the `geocode` function itself:

```
getCurrentAddress = function(location, currgeocoder) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        currgeocoder.geocode({
            'location': location
        }, function (results, status) {

            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                console.log("Results:::" + JSON.stringify(results[0]));
                resolve(results)

            } else {
                reject('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' 
                + status);
            }
        })
    });
};

getCurrentAddress(/*some location data*/, this.currgeocoder)
    .then(function(results) { console.log(results); //pass to MongoDB here})
    .catch(function(error) { console.error(error); //handle error})
```

Comment: Hi, I was trying below code but still this.value is console it undefined

Comment: this.getCurrentAddress(myLatlng, this.currgeocoder).then(
        function (results) {
          console.log("string:::" + JSON.stringify(results[0].formatted_address));
          this.value = results[0].formatted_address;
        }).catch(function (error) {
          console.error(error);
        })

Comment: Why are you adding `this` to your code? What is the context of the code where it is required? This may not always be as what you think it is. Inside the `.then` it probably is referencing global scope, which is not what you want.